# Trying to install Ubuntu

Tags: 15.04

I'm trying to install Ubuntu 15.04 on my desktop computer,  which currently has Windows 10 installed.  I have it on a Bootable USB stick,  but when I boot it,  it sends me to Ubuntu login screen,  even though I have not installed it and I don't have a password or username. Anyone else experienced this problem?  If so,  what did you do?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to login with "ubuntu" as user and a blank password.
You should find a `install` desktop entry, although this probably should not happen.

Comment: Tried that, the screen goes black for a minute,  then I end up there again.

Answer (score 0):

change boot preference order:
while loading use Delete button to go to boot settings,
 there you can change